# How to count records and group by date including days with 0 records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In ActiveRecord, how would one query an `Event` model to get a number of records created every day, including days where no records were created?

For example, if I created events on four out of seven days this week, I would want it to return `[2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 7, 3]`.

So far my query looks like this:
`Event.where(name: name).order('date(created_at)').group('date(created_at)').count.values`, but it only returns `[2, 4, 1, 7, 3]` which will not work when creating a graph of events created over the last X days.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to roll this on your own, just use [this](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) library. It handles all the edgecases for you, including differening weekly start days, ranges that begin with no records, etc.

The answer to your specific question would be:

```
# Unscope is optional, but probably what you want if there is a default_scope.
Event
  .unscoped
  .group_by_day(:created_at)
  .where(name: name)
  .count
```

but if you wanted it for a time range make sure not to put it in the where clause because that will miss the empty values at the beginning and end of the range.

```
range = 10.days.ago..2.days.ago

Event
  .unscoped
  .group_by_day(:created_at, range: range)
  .where(name: name)
  .count
```

And it will include values across the entire range.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Once you have got the group counts,

```
event_counts_hash = Event.where(name: name).order('date(created_at)').group('date(created_at)').count

record_count_array = [0] * 7

event_counts_hash.each { |k, v| count_array[k.cwday] = v  }
```

You should get your weekday counts in your count_array.

Comment: This works, yes, but is inefficient. Is there any way to get this directly from the query?

Answer (score -1):

I recently open sourced [chart_data.js](https://github.com/nicolasgarnil/chart_data.js) (WIP), a client-side micro library which handles those cases in which you need to represent time series data but the series are incomplete.

Example:

```
var from = moment('20140101', 'YYYYMMDD');
var to = moment('20140101', 'YYYYMMDD');

var sampleData = [['2014', '01', '01', '100'], ['2014', '03', '01', '300'], ['2014', '04', '01', '100']];

var chartData = new ChartData(sampleData, from, to, 'months');
var data = chartData.data; 

// [1388534400000, 100], [1391212800000, 0], [1393632000000, 300], [1396310400000, 400]
```

Have a look at it, I hope you find it useful and will appreciate your feedback.